# Not all modules are compiled with -Gy (function comdat), build without incremental LTCG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am building a project solution which was configured with vs2015

```
Platform Toolset - Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
Windows sdk version - 8.1
```

When I am trying to retarget the solution to **Visual Studio 2019 (v142)**,**windows sdk 10.0 (latest)**, the project builds fine but gives a warning message as :

```
Not all modules are compiled with -Gy (function comdat), build without incremental LTCG.
```

The generated executable is suppose to open a GUI for the application but the newly generated doesn't seem to do so.

I tried to change the linking option at the location:

```
C/C++ ➔ Code Generation ➔ Enable Function-Level Linking
```

to **No(/Gy-)** but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you force a clean and full build after making the changes to the project settings ?

Comment: Did you set [/LTCG: OFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation?view=msvc-170)? Try creating a new project in vs2019. Then  copy the code and compile. Will the problem happen again?

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes I did a clean build after retargeting

Comment: Have you tried copying the code to vs2019 manually and recompiling?